# Why I cannot update gem?

Tags: rubygems

My current version of Spaceship is 0.38.5.
Then I was using

```
gem update spaceship
```

to update the library:
Then I got : Nothing to update
But I am really sure the last version of Spaceship is 0.39.0.

I have no choice to update the spaceship by gem install.

```
gem install spaceship
```

Then I get both 0.38.5 and 0.39.0.
I must clean up the old version of spaceship.

Any expert can tell me why my gem update not working?

Thank you in advance!
:)